# export array column from PySpark dataframe to csv without formatting

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have an array column in pyspark dataframe but while I am writing the dataframe to CSV the column is getting formatted

Data:

```
    Column_A                                                 
 2323,2426,6058285,6287,1257                                 
 2491,6317206,10271,8264,3763                                
 3121,4106,2759,4115,6058399                                 
 1488,7675,6048745,1509,183158                               
 2491,8264,637,8929,7474
```

when Exported to CSV there is an additional comma that's getting added, in other words it's taking the entire array as a single column and formatting it to a number rounding off the last characters.

[image]

This is the code i am using:

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.save(path='csv_location', header=True, mode='overwrite', format='csv',fmt='%s')
```

what else should I add or change to make sure it's exporting correctly

Comment: Can you show where the extra comma is getting added? It looks more like the issue is that it is looking at each line like a number instead of a row entry.

Comment: i had updated the question correctly, column is not taking as array and instead getting formatted

for ex: 2323,2426,6058285,6287,1257
once exported to csv i am seeing data as
  23,232,426,605,828,500,000,000 like the data is getting formatted.

Comment: How would a single column turn into a 5x5? Is the first row supposed to have `2323,2426,6058285,6287,1257` as its entry? Or are you trying to create a 5x5 csv (which wouldn't make sense to have `Column_A`).

Comment: Column is an array and it has more rows but i just copied only few

Comment: You should give more correct and reproducible dataset.